# Kendo-vue-ui wrapper kendo-grid-column format phone number in grid

Tags: vuejs2, kendo-ui-vue

I have been trying to use vuejs filter in `kendo-grid-column`

```
<kendo-grid-column field="phone" title="Phone" :template="`kendo.toString(phone) | phoneformat`" width="10%"></kendo-grid-column>
```

Rather being displayed as formatted string the result is displayed as

[image: Output displayed as]

Filter I am using as:

```
const filters = [
  {
    name: "phoneformat",
    execute: value => {
        debugger
      var piece1 = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3); //123
      var piece2 = phoneNumber.substring(3, 6); //456
      var piece3 = phoneNumber.substring(6); //7890

      //should return (123)456-7890
      return kendo.format("({0})-{1}-{2}", piece1, piece2, piece3);
    }
  }
];

export default filters;
```

I have been registering the filter globally as:

```
import filters from './shared/extension'

filters.forEach(f => {
   Vue.filter(f.name, f.execute)
})
```

Help me what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> :template="`kendo.toString(phone) | phoneformat`"
> ```

You have backticks around the `:template` attribute value, meaning you're binding the `template` prop to a [JavaScript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which evaluates to the literal string

```js
"kendo.toString(phone) | phoneformat"
```

The solution is to simply bind an expression instead

```html
<kendo-grid-column :template="phone | phoneformat" ...
```

See

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props

Comment: i have tried the solution, but getting the error,

`Property or method "kendo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property...`

Comment: Well, you haven't shown your `data` or `computed` properties so how would I know. Try just `:template="phone | phoneFormat"` (see updated answer)

Comment: `phone` is not my  custom `data` or computed properties it the properties that directly bind to the `kendo-grid-column` from the `api call`.  May be i need to return `phone` from some `methods`. and it will filter properly.